# Display server-side validation errors on angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I want to display server side validation error using the angular form mechanism, so on my http.post catch function i have this code:

```
.catch(function(fieldErrors){    
  angular.forEach(fieldErrors, function(fieldError){
    vm.agreementForm[fieldError.field].$setValidity(fieldError.validationErrorCode, false); 
  });
})
```

that set fields with error as invalid and set a validation error code. 
The problem with this solution is that required to set manually field validity to true on value change if custom validation error codes are provided from server (e.g. custom server side validation code).

There a better way to do that?

Thank you in adivice